# Find substring and replace with another html/angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, json, replace, find

Hi I've got an object like this:

```
{
    "Properties": [
      "Name: Steven",
      "Country: Australia"
    ]
}
```

I get this object with this string from our backend. Now I have to show it in our popup in html. I do it like this:

```
<div>{{ object.Properties }}</div>
```

It works, I get the string in follow format in my popup: **Name: Steven,Country: Australia**

The goal is, that I get follow format (without a comma and with a brake after every item and perhaps a horizontal solid line):

**Name: Steven**

**Country: Australia**

I tried an ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="property in object.Properties">{{ property }}<br></div>
```

It doesn't work. Now I tried to find the comma in the string and replace it with a br-tag. Would this work? I have no idea how to do this and if it is possible, so I choosed to ask here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that `Properties` isn't a hashtable, even though the `:` characters inside the strings make it seem so. Instead, it's just an array of strings.

Try this instead:

```js
angular
  .module("demo", [])
  .controller("demo", function($scope) {
    $scope.object = {
      "Properties": [
        "Name: Steven",
        "Country: Australia"
      ]
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demo">
  <div ng-repeat="prop in object.Properties">
    {{ prop.split(": ")[0] }}:
    {{ prop.split(": ")[1] }}
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

This could still use some practices improvements, e.g. the `split`ting is something you'd rather do inside the code so it could be unit tested. The details would be up to your specific coding conventions, but here's another version with some quick improvements (where at the least all code is brought from the view to the controller side):

```js
angular
  .module("demo", [])
  .controller("demo", function($scope) {
    var data = {
      "Properties": [
        "Name: Steven",
        "Country: Australia"
      ]
    };

    $scope.props = data["Properties"].map(function(p) {
      var parts = p.split(": ");
      if (parts.length !== 2) {
        throw "Unexpected data " + p;
      }
      return {
        key: parts[0],
        value: parts[1]
      };
    });
  });
```

```css
th, td { padding: 5px; background: silver; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demo">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="prop in props">
      <th>{{prop.key}}</th>
      <td>{{prop.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```